# How can I extract specific values from a JSON array in Kusto Query Language?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

### Kusto Query to parse JSON array and gather all values of a given property

What is the best way to query a specific key values in an JSON array. Here is a sample input of two rows, where the third column 'DProducts' is dynamic column

```
OrgId,  OrgName, DProducts (dynamic)
581,    ABC,    [{"Id":"123","Name":"abc","PlanId":"af3"},{"Id":"234","Name":"bcd","PlanId":"aee3"}]
582,    ABCD,   [{"Id":"12345","Name":"abcfg","PlanId":"afg3"},{"Id":"234","Name":"bcd","PlanId":"aee3"}]
583,    CDEF,   []
```

Looking to generate an output in the below format.

```
OrgId,  OrgName, DProducts_name
581,    ABC,    ["abc" , "bcd"]
582,    ABCD,   ["abcfg" , "bcd"]
583,    CDEF,   []
```

Tried

```
| mv-expand DProducts
| project OrgId, OrgName,DProducts["Name"]
```

This returns new row for each element name from the json
i.e

```
OrgId,  OrgName, DProducts_name
581,    ABC,    "abc"
581,    ABC,    "bcd"
582,    ABCD,   "abcfg"
582,    ABCD,   "bcd"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a combination of the [`mv-apply` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) and the [`make_list()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction).

for example:

```
datatable(OrgId: int, OrgName: string, DProducts: dynamic)
[
    581, 'ABC', dynamic([{"Id": "123", "Name": "abc", "PlanId": "af3"}, {"Id": "234", "Name": "bcd", "PlanId": "aee3"}]),
    582, 'ABCD', dynamic([{"Id": "12345", "Name": "abcfg", "PlanId": "afg3"}, {"Id": "234", "Name": "bcd", "PlanId": "aee3"}]),
    583, 'CDEF', dynamic([]),
]
| mv-apply DProducts on (
    project name = DProducts.Name
    | summarize DProducts_name = make_list(name)
)
```

| OrgId | OrgName | DProducts_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 581 | ABC | [ "abc", "bcd" ] |
| 582 | ABCD | [ "abcfg", "bcd" ] |
| 583 | CDEF | [] |

Comment: Thank you Yoni L. Your suggestion worked !!. Appreciate your time and efforts